# javascript button help - keeps redirecting to Home tab on save

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Need help with this button. Keeps returning me to the Home tab. How can I make it return to the case where the button began?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 

var tskObj = new sforce.SObject("Task");
tskObj.Status = "Not Started"; 
tskObj.RecordTypeId ="012Q0000000DIKh"; 
tskObj.OwnerId ="{!$User.Id}"; 
tskObj.WhoId ="{!Case.ContactId}";
tskObj.WhatId="{!Case.Id}";
tskObj.Priority ="Normal"; 
tskObj.Subject ="VOC VEP Follow Up Request"; 

var result = sforce.connection.create([tskObj]); 

if (result[0].success=="false") { 
    alert(result[0].errors.message); 
} else { 
    var newURL = "/" + result[0].id + "/e"; 
    window.top.location = newURL; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a return URL parameter, change your newURL to:

```
var newURL = "/" + result[0].id + "/e?retURL=%2F{!Case.Id} ";
```

Comment: doh!! I knew it was going to be something "simple" like that. I scoured the internet trying to find the answer!! Thank you Rao.

Comment: most welcome :)